How can I prove a case of covid for UK travel insurance?
We're in the UK. Day before we are due to go away and someone in the family has returned a positive covid test. I insured the trip and checking the small print it says:

You’ll need to provide proof of a positive Covid-19 test as certified by a registered medical practitioner, a registered lateral flow test or if the lateral flow test can’t be registered, an acceptable letter from the NHS confirming the positive Covid-19 result. Photographs of a lateral flow test are not acceptable evidence.

The insurance phone lines are closed and don't open until Monday. Neither does our doctor's surgery.
So: does anyone know what this means in practical terms? What is a "registered" test now that the NHS no longer gives them out and collects data? Can I get one anywhere, or how else do I go about "proving" this is genuine so we can claim?

Which insurance company?

@Traveller Admiral.

How bad are the symptoms? At this point of the mutation cycle its fully equivalent to getting a cold. Might be easier to just travel.

What is the reason for not wanting to travel? Not meeting Covid requirements if the destination country (are there any left?), feeling too sick/tired for the trip, not wanting to spread it (a face mask is enough for that)?

Search for 'fit to fly' COVID tests.  Some services have a same day PCR service, eg Local PCR has testing centres in London and Birmingham.
Lloyds Pharmacy also has a testing service using lateral flow tests where they can do on the spot certification (although they don't recommend it if you have COVID).
As to what a 'registered medical practitioner' means, that's a matter for your insurance.  But there will be a duty pharmacist (registered with the General Pharmaceutical Council) and perhaps they can sign the test?
